# Prove the asymptote $\Gamma \left(x+\frac{1}{\Gamma(x-y)} \right)/ \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(x-y)} \right) \asymp (x-2)^y$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: limits, asymptotics, gamma-function, pochhammer-symbol

I noticed it first for Pochhammer symbols for integers:

$$\left( \frac{1}{n!} \right)_n \asymp \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty$$

$$\left( \frac{1}{n!} \right)_{n+1} \asymp 1 \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty$$

And so on.

Writing explicitly, for example, the last expression:

$$\left( \frac{1}{n!} \right)_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(n!)^{n+1}} (n!+1)(2n!+1) \cdots (n n!+1)$$

I don't see how to prove the limit.

In general, for the integer case, we seem to have:

> $$\left( \frac{1}{(n-k)!} \right)_{n+1} \asymp (n-1)^k \quad \text{as} \quad n \to \infty$$

Generalizing with the Gamma function, it turns to:

> $$\frac{\Gamma \left(x+\frac{1}{\Gamma(x-y)} \right) }{ \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{\Gamma(x-y)} \right)} \asymp (x-2)^y \quad \text{as} \quad  x \to \infty \tag{1}$$

We should also assume $x >> y$.

Which seems to work numerically (see the plots below):

[image]

> How can we prove $(1)$ for the real case, or at least for the integer case?

Comment: Perhaps Stirling's approximation?

Comment: @SimpleArt, maybe, I forgot about it. But we have nested Gammas here...

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying it right now.

Comment: @SimpleArt, you could also assume $x >> y$, since it doesn't work otherwise

Comment: $$\frac{\Gamma\left(x+\frac1{\Gamma(x-y)}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac1{\Gamma(x-y)}\right)}\sim\sqrt{x\left(\frac{x-y}e\right)^{x-y}\sqrt{2\pi (x-y)}}\left(x+\frac{e^{x-y}}{(x-y)^{x-y}\sqrt{2\pi (x-y)}}\right)^xe^{-x}\left(x(\frac{x-y}e)^{x-y}\sqrt{2\pi (x-y)}+1\right)^{\frac{e^{x-y}}{(x-y)^{x-y}\sqrt{2\pi (x-y)}}}$$ Hope you can use this?

Comment: @SimpleArt, wow, impressive work, thank you. But I don't really want to deal with this expression right now.

Comment: I am truly in agreeance.  I'll see if I can work it out myself.

Comment: Regarding the first Pochhammer symbol in your post, note that $$\left( \frac{1}{n!} \right)_n=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\left( \frac{1}{n!}+k \right)
=\frac{1}{n!}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left[k\cdot\left(1+ \frac{1}{n!\cdot k} \right)\right]=\frac{1}{n}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1+ \frac{1}{n!\cdot k} \right)$$
hence $$1\leqslant n\cdot\left( \frac{1}{n!} \right)_n\leqslant\left(1+ \frac{1}{n!} \right)^{n-1}\leqslant e^{n/n!}\to1$$ which proves that the $\asymp$ is actually a full equivalent, and the same holds for ...

Comment: $$\left( \frac{1}{n!} \right)_{n+1}=\left( \frac{1}{n!} \right)_n\left( \frac{1}{n!}+n \right)=\left( \frac{1}{n!} \right)_n\cdot n\cdot\left( 1+\frac{1}{n\cdot n!} \right)$$ The same strategy should lead you to a proof for every other quantity you are interested in in your post.

Comment: @Did, thank you. That's very clear. I actually don't know what other sign instead of $\asymp$ should I use

Comment: The sign to denote $\lim f(x)/g(x)=1$ is $f(x)\sim g(x)$. Re the ratio of Gammas, note that this is $$\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x-y)}\prod_{k=1}^x\left(1+\frac{1}{k\cdot\Gamma(x-y)}\right)$$ where $$\frac{\Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(x-y)}\sim x^y$$ and $$1\leqslant\prod_{k=1}^x\left(1+\frac{1}{k\Gamma(x-y)}\right)\leqslant\left(1+\frac{1}{\Gamma(x-y)}\right)^x\to1$$ hence indeed an equivalent of the whole stuff when $x\to\infty$, for every fixed $y$, is $x^y$.